# Set up subdomains in IIS 7, Windows Server 2008

Tags: iis-7.5, subdomain

I have searched and searched, nothing that I have found has worked yet.

The Problem: A brochure was published with subdomains that don't exist. I need to create and redirect those subdomains to existing pages on our site.

How do I set up a subdomain in IIS 7? How do I correctly point the DNS to the subdomain? I'm sorry for the newb question, but I am new to IIS.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you serve your public DNS yourself, or is it handed by a third party (likely your domain registrar)?

Answer (score 2):

you shouldn't need to set up a sub domain just alter the bindings of the site to add the sub domain, I believe this should do what you need, have a look at [this.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731692%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

An alternative is to edit the DNS and add a CNAME for the sub domain pointing to whatever it is meant to point to.

Answer (score 0):

Use host headers.  Create a iis website with host header mysubdomain.mydomain.com
then you can do a redirect on that site.